# Como criar arrays a partir de um array filtrando pela letra inicial dos valores? Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
var itens = ['Lápis', 'Lapiseira','Papel', 'Pasta', 'Pilot', 'Pincel']
```

A partir desse array eu gostaria de criar arrays separados pela primeira letra de cada item.

Exemplo:

```
['Lápis', 'Lapiseira']
['Papel', 'Pasta', 'Pilot', 'Pincel']
```

Comment: Pode usar o `.charAt(0)` em resumo ele pega primeiro caracter da seguencia da palavra.https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt   e usar um filter para comparar se a primeira letra corresponde ao que se pede

Comment: `var L = itens.filter(item => item.charAt(0) === "L");`   dessa forma separara cada qual com sua sequencia

Comment: e sim o filter retorna um novo array,https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Me parece que esta pergunta tem a resposta que você procura
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837432/how-to-split-array-of-strings-into-sets-of-arrays-alphabetically-in-javascript

Comment: O problema de usar `filter` (e também a resposta abaixo) é que vc vai percorrer o array várias vezes (uma vez para cada letra), mas não precisa disso. Dá pra criar tudo em um único loop: https://ideone.com/QdnYeu - Claro que se for considerar outros casos, tem que adaptar (por exemplo, não diferenciar maiúsculas e minúsculas, desconsiderar acentos, etc), mas aí só muda a forma de pegar a primeira letra (porém, a ideia básica continua a mesma).

Answer (score -2):

#### Criar arrays a partir de um array filtrando pela letra inicial.

```js
let items = ['Lápis', 'Lapiseira','Papel', 'Pasta', 'Pilot', 'Pincel'];

items.sort(new Intl.Collator().compare); // Opcional se a intenção não for a de ordenar as palavras de forma alfanumérica dentro dentro do mesmo grupo de itens.

for (let uCP = 0; uCP <= 0x2FFFF; uCP++) {
    let itemsGroup = [];
    for (const item of items) {
        item
            .toString() // Opcional se o valor de "item" for exclusivamente typeof String.
            .normalize('NFD') // Para agrupar itens com a mesma letra inicial, com, ou sem sinal gráfico. Por exemplo, palavras começadas por 'a', 'á' ou 'à' pertencem ao mesmo grupo de itens.
            .toLowerCase() // Para agrupar itens com letra inicial com o mesmo significado fonético (por exemplo: "p" === "P").
            .codePointAt(0) === uCP && itemsGroup.push(item);
    }

    '0' in itemsGroup && console.log(itemsGroup);
}
```

Usando o método `.filter`:

```js
let items = ['Lápis', 'Lapiseira', 'Papel', 'Pasta', 'Pilot', 'Pincel'];

items.sort(new Intl.Collator().compare);

for (let uCP = 0; uCP <= 0x2FFFF; uCP++) {
    let itemsGroup = items.filter(item =>
        `${item}`
            .normalize('NFD')
            .toLowerCase()
            .codePointAt(0) === uCP
    );

    '0' in itemsGroup && console.log(itemsGroup);
}
```

Comment: Olá, joão. É legal querer colaborar, mas é importante também que as soluções sejam cuidadosas do ponto de vista técnico. Seu código está iterando a lista uma vez para cada caractere de 0 a 0x2ffff desnecessariamente, importante revisar isso. A parte de normalização do caractere está boa, mas o loop externo é "desproporcional" (pra tentar usar uma palavra suave). Fica a sugestão de aplicar a normalização apenas para extrair o caractere, e usar um loop só (a inicial pode ser chave de um objeto, contendo os itens, assim só processa uma vez cada ítem). Como otimização pode fazer o sort por grupo.

Comment: Lembrando que uma das idéias do site é que tudo pode ser editado e aprimorado, abrindo a postagem para revisão da classificação inclusive.

Comment: E por que escolheu especificamente o 0x2FFFF? A versão atual do Unicode ([15.0](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/)) define 149186 caracteres, que em hexa é 0x246c2

Comment: Além disso, não precisa percorrer todos os caracteres Unicode, pra depois ver se o array tem alguma palavra que começa com ele. É mais simples percorrer o array uma única vez, e para cada elemento vc pega a primeira letra e adiciona no array correspondente (verificando primeiro se ele ainda não existe), algo [assim](https://ideone.com/QdnYeu). Se for para não diferenciar maiúsculas e minúsculas, ou se for ignorar acentos, basta mudar a forma de pegar a primeira letra (usando `normalize` etc como vc fez), mas aí é só adaptar. A diferença é brutal, veja: https://jsbench.me/lvle2rixto/1